# Using a batch program, how to loop and read lines in a csv file, get the matching value, then assign it as password to a PDF

Tags: windows, pdf, batch-file, passwords, pdf-generation

I need some help again. I am currently doing a batch program that does the following:

In the \Reports\ folder several text files are stored. Example,

```
 - A_000001.txt
 - A_000002.txt
 - B_000001.txt
 - B_000002.txt
 - C_000001.txt
 - C_000002.txt
 - D_000001.txt
 - D_000002.txt
 - E_000001.txt
 - E_000002.txt
 - F_000001.txt
 - F_000002.txt
```

1. The batch program individually converts all the text files into PDF with the use of "AdultPDF Txt to PDF converter" command line functions.
2. The converted PDF files which have the same last 6 characters on their filenames (example, `A_000001.pdf`,...`F_000001.pdf`) are combined into a single PDF then given an output filename `R_000001.pdf`. The combined PDF files are stored into the `\Reports\PDF Reports\` folder.
3. The last thing I would want to do in my batch program is to assign a password to the combined PDF file. The password will come from a csv file (`passwords.csv`) that contains the following columns:

filename of the combined PDF,password for the PDF

for example:

```
 - R_000001.pdf,abcd1234
 - R_000002.pdf,efgh5678
 - R_000003.pdf,ijkl0910
```

In order to address items number 2 & 3, I installed the program PDFTK (or PDF ToolKit). It has Command Line functions that combines PDF files with different parameters, including adding password into a PDF file. Below is a line from my batch program that shows how to combine multiple PDF files into one, and adding a password into the PDF file.

`pdftk *%%j.pdf cat output "PDF Reports\R_%%j.pdf" user_pw abcd1234`

I would like to know how will I do it wherein for example, if the combined PDF's filename is R_000002.pdf, the batch program will look through the filenames listed in passwords.csv and if the matching filename is found, then the password next to it (which is efgh5678) will be assigned to the combined PDF.

Below is the complete batch program I have accomplished so far. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET prevsuff=::

for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_." %%i in ('dir ?_*.txt /b ^|sort /+2') do IF NOT !prevsuff!==%%j (
 SET prevsuff=%%j
 IF EXIST A_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF A_%%j.txt A_%%j.pdf -pps4 -pfs10.9
 IF EXIST B_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF B_%%j.txt B_%%j.pdf -pps4 -pfs8.9
 IF EXIST C_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF C_%%j.txt C_%%j.pdf -pps4 -plm50 -prm50 -pfs7.9
 IF EXIST D_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF D_%%j.txt D_%%j.pdf -pps4 -plm60 -prm60 -pfs8.9
 IF EXIST E_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF E_%%j.txt E_%%j.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs10
 IF EXIST F_%%j.txt TXTtoPDF F_%%j.txt F_%%j.pdf -pps5 -pot -pfs12
 pdftk *%%j.pdf cat output "PDF Reports\R_%%j.pdf" user_pw abcd1234
)
```

Comment: Your question is beyond the scope of a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read csv, use

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=, TOKENS=1,2" %%p IN (csvfile) DO command
```

For each line in *csvfile*, *command* is called. *%%p* will contain pdf filename and *%%q* will contain password.

To search a specific pdf:

```
FOR /F "DELIMS=, TOKENS=1,2" %%p IN (csvfile) DO IF /I "%%p"=="R_%%j.pdf" pdftk *%%j.pdf cat output "PDF Reports\R_%%j.pdf" user_pw %%q
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code you have provided. It was short and simple, but worked perfectly. That was really great! I would like to ask, in the part "DO IF /I", what is the /I switch for? This is the first time I encountered that switch in a for loop statement.

Comment: `/I` in `IF` means case insensitive. You can see other options using `IF /?` from command line, or any other command than `IF`.